# React Native Dynamically created components not rendering on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a list by dynamically adding the list items to an array in the `state` and then using the `map` operator to iterate over them. However, the new list items are only rendered after the second click on the button that handles the `setState` method. Any pointers on resolving this?

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        requirements:[], // Placeholder array in state
        currentRequirement
    }
}
...
```

And in my `render` method I have this.

```
{
    this.state.requirements.map((el,i) => (
        <TouchableOpacity key={i}>
         <BulletItem text={el}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ))
}
<FormInput 
    onChangeText={(value) => { 
        this.setState({ currentRequirement: value})}
    } 
    placeholder="Enter a new requirement"
/>

<Button 
    title="Add Requirement" 
    onPress={() => {
             this.onAddRequirementComponent()
    }}
/>
```

The method for handling the `setState` is this.

```
onAddRequirementComponent() {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        requirements: [...previousState.requirements, this.state.currentRequirement],
        currentRequirement:''
    }))
}
```

#### UPDATE : FULL COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Picker, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { BulletItem, TagCloud } from "../components/index";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import {
    Button,
    Header,
    FormInput,
    FormLabel,
} from 'react-native-elements';
export default class ListScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jobtype: '',
            level: '',
            requirements: [],
            benefits: [],
            currentRequirement: '',
            currentBenefit: ''
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header
                    backgroundColor='#fff'
                    borderBottomWidth={0}
                    leftComponent={{ icon: 'corner-up-left', color: '#333', type: 'feather', onPress: () => { Actions.pop() } }}
                    centerComponent={{ text: 'Create New Job', fontFamily: 'VarelaRound-Regular', style: { color: '#333', fontSize: 18 } }}
                    rightComponent={{ icon: 'options', color: '#333', type: 'simple-line-icon' }} />
                <ScrollView>
                    <FormLabel>Job Title</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput placeholder="e.g. Full Stack Javascript Developer"/>
                    <FormLabel >REQUIREMENTS</FormLabel>
                    {
                        this.state.requirements.map((el, i) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity key={i}><BulletItem containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#EFF0F2', borderRadius: 4 }} style={{ backgroundColor: '#EFF0F2' }} text={el} /></TouchableOpacity>
                        ))
                    }
                                <FormInput 
                    onChangeText={(value) => { 
                        this.setState({ currentRequirement: value})}
                    } 
                    placeholder="Enter a new requirement"
                />

                <Button 
                    title="Add Requirement" 
                    onPress={() => {
                            this.onAddRequirementComponent()
                    }}
                />
                    <FormLabel style={{ fontFamily: 'VarelaRound-Regular', color: '#333' }} labelStyle={{ fontFamily: 'VarelaRound-Regular', color: '#333' }}>BENEFITS</FormLabel>
                    {
                        this.state.benefits.map((el, i) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity key={i}><BulletItem text={el} /></TouchableOpacity>
                        ))
                    }
                    <FormInput value={this.state.currentBenefit} onChangeText={(value) => { this.setState({ currentBenefit: value }) }} placeholder="3 years experience developing Javascript apps" />
                    <Button title="Add" onPress={() => { this.onAddBenefitComponent() }}/>
                    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.jobtype}
                        style={{ height: 50, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#EFF0F2' }}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ jobtype: itemValue })}>
                        <Picker.Item label="Full Time" value="fulltime" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Part Time" value="parttime" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Contract" value="contract" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Remote" value="remote" />
                    </Picker>
                    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.level}
                        style={{ height: 50, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#EFF0F2' }}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ level: itemValue })}>
                        <Picker.Item label="Junior" value="junior" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Mid-Level" value="mid" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Management" value="management" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Senior" value="senior" />
                    </Picker>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }

    onAddRequirementComponent() {
        if (this.state.currentRequirement)
            this.setState(previousState => ({
                requirements: [...previousState.requirements, this.state.currentRequirement],
                currentRequirement: ''
            }))
    }

    onAddBenefitComponent() {
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            benefits: [...previousState.benefits, this.state.currentBenefit],
            currentBenefit: ''
        }))

    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    }
});
```

Comment: If you click the button twice, are 2 items rendered, or does it take 2 clicks to only get 1 item added to the array and re-rendered?

Comment: @Tholle only one item is rendered after the second click

Comment: Alright, that's frustrating. Your `setState` looks correct. You could use `previousState.currentRequirement`, but that's not the issue. How is the `Button` component implemented? Maybe it uses the `onPress` method on double click.

Comment: @Tholle the button is from the `react-native-elements` ui library. I suspected the same and changed it to a simple `Text` but still no luck. I suspected lag on my `Genymotion` emulator and ran it on physical device - no luck either.

Comment: Alright. Could you include your entire component? There might be something else subtle going on.

Comment: @Thole also tried to force a re-render with `this.forceUpdate()` that did not work either. Am absolutely stumped at the moment.

Comment: And if you `console.log(this.state.requirements);` in the beginning of the render method it will still not contain an element until you click twice? Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

This is the core logical part and works perfectly. I used only native elements like `TextInput`. The only change I made to make the `TextInput` to full controlled by adding `value={this.state.currentRequirement}` plus the suggestion of @Tholle for the usage of `previousState`.

```
class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    requirements: [],
    currentRequirement: ''
  }

  onAddRequirementComponent() {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      requirements: [...previousState.requirements, previousState.currentRequirement],
      currentRequirement:''
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={(value) => { 
          this.setState({ currentRequirement: value})}
        }
        value={this.state.currentRequirement}
        />

        { this.state.requirements.map((el,i) => (
            <Text key={i}>{el}</Text>
        ))}

        <Button 
          title="Add Requirement" 
          onPress={() => {
            this.onAddRequirementComponent()
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```